# Exponential Distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm having some trouble understanding the mechanics of how to solve with this distribution.  The question:

The number of years that a washing machine functions is a random variable whose hazard rate function is given by

$$
 \lambda(t)=
 \begin{cases}
  0.2,          & 0   <  t   <  2 \\
  0.2 + 3(t-2), & 2 \leq t \leq 5 \\
  1.1,         & t > 5 \\
 \end{cases}
$$

(a) What is the probability that the machine will still be working $6$ years after being purchased?

(b) If it is still working $6$ years after being purchased, then what is the conditional probability that it will fail within the next $2$ years?

I understand the formula is $λe^{-λt}$ and I think I need to integrate this for $t$ from $0$ to $6$.

However my answer is way off from the answer in the solutions page.

Does anybody have time for a step by step solution?

Much appreciated.

Comment: The answer should be e^-3.45.  I'm getting -e^1.1.  I'm using CDF 1 - e^λt and plugging in 1.1 for F(6).  I think this is wrong but my book does not explain this well.

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment on an answer that was deleted a short while ago, the $\lambda$ that you write in $\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$ is _not_ the same as the $\lambda(t)$ in the question (hazard rates are often denoted by a different symbol, e.g. $h(t)$). The choice of notation by the author of your book is regrettable and no doubt adds to the difficulties of understanding the explanations.

Comment: $P\{X > 6\}= e^{-3.45}$ will not be the correct answer if the hazard rate is as shown now, but _will_ be the correct answer if the value were $0.2 + 0.3(t-2)$ for $t \in [2,5]$, thus making the hazard rate a piecewise linear continuous function.

Comment: That's the solution listed:                             P{X > 6} = exp{ − 0 to 6 integral( λ(t)dt) } = e −3.45

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly I integrate the hazard function - for instance if I integrate from 0 to 6, I integrate from 0 to 2 .2, 2 to 5 .2 + .3(t-2), and 5 to 6 1.1, no?

Comment: Yes, that is what you integrate. But if you understand that the integral gives the area under the curve, you might be able to find the area without explicit integration by using standard results such as area of a rectangle, and area of a trapezoid.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle P\{X > T\} =\exp\left(-\int_0^T h(t)\,\,\mathrm dt\right)$ where $h(t)$ is the hazard rate. So calculate the area under the hazard rate function from $0$ to $6$ and apply the formula to get the probability that the machine has not failed in the first $6$ years.

For part (b), you are asked for 
$\displaystyle P\{X \leq 8\mid X > 6\} 
= \frac{P\{\{X \leq 8\}\cap \{X >6\}\}}{P\{X > 6\}}
= \frac{P\{6 < X \leq 8\}}{P\{X > 6\}}$ which you should be able to work out for
yourself based on the relationship between the hazard rate and the complementary
CDF that is given in the first paragraph.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up some of the confusion